# How to read "a b.txt" in bundle directory iOS

Tags: ios, bundle, readfile

I have a problem right now. I want to read content of file which one have space in file name like "a b.txt" in budle directory. How to do that?

Thanks before. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* filePath= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"a b" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString* txt= [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

The space in the filename should not cause a problem.